# VBA copy to zip file returns error

Tags: vba, zip

I've written a script to add all files in a folder to a zip file using code adapted from www.rondebruin.nl, but I keep getting an error 'Object variable or With block variable not set'.

```
Function ZipDir(FolderName As String, ZipName As String) As String
'Copied from: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm
Dim FileNameZip ', FolderName
Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
Dim oApp As Object

'Create empty Zip File
NewZip ZipName

Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'Copy the files to the compressed folder
oApp.Namespace(ZipName).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items '<<ERROR HERE

'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
On Error Resume Next
Do Until oApp.Namespace(ZipName).items.Count = _
    oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items.Count
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & ZipName
End Function
```

The code errors on the `oApp.Namespace(ZipName).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items` line. However if I explicitly declare the source and destination files like so: `oApp.Namespace("C:\MyZip.Zip").CopyHere "C:\Temp\MyFile.pdf"`

If I change Either the zip name, or the file name from above, then it errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get valid paths from ZipName and FolderName?

Comment: Yes. I even tried using the immediate window - `?zipname` and `?Foldername`, then pasting those values back into the code... When I paste the actual value it works, but when I use ZipName or FolderName it doesn't work...

Comment: So where is it getting ZipName and FolderName from? Are they in immediate window from the method that's calling this function or for this function itself? If you do a Debug.Print for each of those does it give you what you expect?

Comment: ZipName and FolderName are passed into the function. Doing a Debug.Print gives me what I'd expect.
Here's a link to a screenshot (note the actual code is a little messier than what I posted above): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-wKk1NwzzccN0R2ZGVudk5WTDA/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `Shell.Application` object, you should pass all paths and filenames as Variants, not string.

If you look at Ron's code you'll see that's what he does.

As he says on that page:

> Note: Do not Dim for example FileNameZip as String in the code
>   examples. This must be a Variant, if you change this the code will not
>   work.

Comment: Thanks SO much for that! Exactly where I went wrong.